# How to create Google documents in Box.com using Box SDK

Tags: c#, box, documents

I'm able to create .txt file with below code:

```
public void CreatFile(string filename,string filetype,string content)
    {
        var authenticator = new TokenProvider(clientId, clientSecret);
        var oAuthToken = authenticator.RefreshAccessToken(refreshToken);
        accessToken = oAuthToken.AccessToken;

        // Instantiate a BoxManager with your api key and a user's auth token
        var boxManager = new BoxManager(accessToken);

        // Create a new file in the root folder
        boxManager.CreateFile(Folder.Root, filename + filetype, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content));
   }
```

And using below i can create office documents files:

```
 public void UploadFile(string filename,string fileType,string fileUrl)
    {
        try
        {
                var authenticator = new TokenProvider(clientId, clientSecret);
                var oAuthToken = authenticator.RefreshAccessToken(refreshToken);
                accessToken = oAuthToken.AccessToken;

                var client = new RestClient("https://upload.box.com/api/2.0");
                var request = new RestRequest("files/content", Method.POST);
                request.AddParameter("parent_id", Folder.Root);

                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

                byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileUrl);

                request.AddFile("filename", byteArray, filename + fileType);

                var responses = client.Execute(request);
                var content = responses.Content;

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

But the same above codes is not working, for Google type documents creation.
I have gone thru many online samples, none of those helped for me.

Please.... help me, how to create Google type documents(.gdoc, .gsheet) in Box.com using Box SDK.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to create a Google document through the Box API. It is possible to do this through the Box web app.